# IIS Throwing error : HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, xml, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I have simple website which I am trying to run through IIS. But on browsing the website it throws error saying

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

[image]

Below is my web.config code that is have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AlphaWeb.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Any help will be great. Thank you

Comment: and what about when you launch it from VS? all fine or the same error?

Comment: @SergeyMatvienko works fine while running on vs

Comment: the error looks like the web.config does not exist in published folder at all...

Comment: here is a couple options:
- open properties of web.config file and check permission.
- try open web.config file with notepad, make some change and save. try to review config from IIS. Restart server/computer and check again. 
- try to create a new empty project and run it from IIS, and then compare your web.config files

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1176834.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an invalid character or encoding on your web.config. Try opening it on a tool like Notepad++ and enable "View > Show Symbol > Show all Characters". You can also try setting it to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score -1):

try to update your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="aspNetCore" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: still throws the same error